# LinkedIn Community Management API create an article post with a link preview

Tags: linkedin-api

Recently our app was able to create LinkedIn posts via UGC Posts API and the URL preview functionality worked perfectly for the article post type when the source URL was provided. But after we migrated to the new API it seems that it is not possible anymore according to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/version/article-ads-integrations?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http

> Article Post API does not support url scraping for article post creation […] it. Instead, API partners need to set article fields such as thumbnail, title and description.

Is there any workaround for that except parsing those fields by yourself and providing them with publishing request?

I've tried to pass only source url with an empty title (both fields are required) in a post creation request, but the result article was crested with that provided data only - so no image was recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the link in another posts type but it seems not working, so there is no workaround you should scrap the link yourself or take the information provided by the user and fill in the object

```
{
      "source":"",
      "title":"",
      "description":"",
      "thumbnail":""
}
```

And this is mentioned in the docs,

> Posts API does not support url scraping for article post creation as
> it introduces level of unpredictability in how a post is going to look
> when API partners create it. Instead, API partners need to set article
> fields such as thumbnail, title and description within the post when
> creating an article post. To create an article post with thumbnail
> image, please use Images API to upload thumbnail image and use the
> ImageUrn on thumbnail field. For more info, please refer to
> ArticleContent API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-02&tabs=http#article-post-creation-sample-request